# Can I render an HTML form inside a Raphael entity?

Tags: html, raphael

I want to draw draggable entities with Raphael, but some of these entities should support handling user input (text lines, forms, etc).
The user input could be done in regular HTML (open to alternatives), but I was curious if Raphael can handle dragging non SVG objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't, sadly. There are other SVG libraries which have more functions. But none of them appeal to me like Raphäel does.

Have a look at these: http://www.farinspace.com/top-svg-javascript-libraries-worth-looking-at/

A nice solution would be an ui event triggern a lightbox. Looks good :)

Comment: http://www.opensourcehunter.com/2010/06/25/40-javascript-lightbox-scriptsincluded-jquery-and-mootools/ It's like a nice popup.

Comment: oh right. what I had in mind is having something similar to an iframe within a SVG rectangle, so if I rotate or move that rectangle, the iframe containing the HTML form will change accordingly.

Comment: can you add more details on the reason why I can't do this? it would complete your answer.

Comment: Raphäel does only do graphics. Not HTML elements. No nested layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently, but I had to patch raphael.js for this. Overall, it was a painful experience. If I had to start another project like this again, I would have created separate native SVG and VML versions.